# Wordpress theme installation issue

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to install a theme on WordPress but the site is not loading as shown in the theme preview. I tried a few more free WordPress themes but the same thing happened. My current WordPress version is 5.0.3.

I also tried installing themes to 4.8.8 WordPress but with the same result.

Following is the theme I want t install:

http://justfreethemes.com/demo/?theme=Alchem

[Alchem Theme Installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2ISI.png)

There are no console errors and I have required xampp configurations on my system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the themes in WordPress have their default templates.

I created a page and assigned the **Front Page Template** to it in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Some Wordpress theme do not include the demo content that you see on the theme preview. You need to manually add a post, pages, navigation, widgets and other cool stuff offered by your theme. Check with the theme author or theme documentation for more info.

Some theme offers to import their demo. You might want to check with your theme support since every theme has different methods.

Answer (score 0):

Try some other wordpress theme that have a demo view after adding it to your wordpress website , if it works , that mean you need to create your page using the theme you want manually